# Breaking sentences up

Tags: phrases, sentence, clauses, sentence-fragments

What is the right term for breaking or dividing a sentence into fragments, wherein each fragment still contains a thought/meaning?

e.g.:

> Sports can ostracize people/ who are not very good at them./

Comment: The smaller sentences are simply called clauses (or fragments). Or do you want to know what is the act of breaking sentences into clauses called?

Comment: I want to know what term is used for those divided clauses (or fragments). I think I heard someone say "natural phrases" before. I just cannot remember well and I am not sure if that's the right term.

Comment: The usual term is _Parsing_. It comes from the Latin word _pars, partis_, which means (unsurprisingly) 'part'. One parses a sentence to analyze it into its **constituents** (that's the term for the kind of coherent part you're looking for. When learning classical languages -- where there are no native speakers -- one learned to parse and _construe_ sentences. Parsing is the analysis -- take it apart -- while construing is the synthesis -- put it together -- to show how the meanings connect. Most syntactic tree diagrams are about parsing, and a _parser_ is a kind of NLP program.

Comment: An example of parsing (the first 7 lines of the _Iliad_) is [available here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Iliadparse.pdf).

Comment: The divided clauses you've parsed out are called just that, *clauses*.

Answer (score -2):

The process of splitting up and analysing a sentence grammatically to see how it works is called *scanning the sentence*. I'm not sure if that's what you mean?